# List of requested topics does not mark topics I have already dismissed

Tags: bug, documentation

List of requested topics in Documentation dashboard does not mark topics I have already dismissed.

All topics look the same:

[image]

Only when I click dismiss and select reason for dismissing it will show message that I have already voted for dismissal of the topic.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how dismissing works. A "dismissed" topic usually disappears after dismissing, but it's not clear what happens then and when it's actually dismissed (others say they see what I dismissed). Marking still active requests as dismissed by you would make more sense.

Comment: @Squidward You can completely dismiss it if you have enough voting power in the tag. If you don't you have to wait for others to use their votes, too.

Comment: @Squidward I am no longer sure under what conditions are topics dismissed. There might be bugs or more than one person has to dismiss it. See related question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332190/after-dismissing-topic-it-is-still-listed-in-documentation-topic-requests-but-n