# After dismissing topic it is still listed in Documentation topic requests, but not my dashboard

Tags: bug, documentation

I have dismissed Delphi topic and I my Documentation dashboard shows 5 topic requests.

[image]

But when I go to Delphi Documentation directly it still lists 6 topic requests.

[image]

[image]

Now, it is not clear to me whether it is a bug in listings or I didn't really dismissed the topic request. I have silver badge in Delphi tag and it seems I should be able to single handedly dismiss topics.